# rewrite Euler equation to the next form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to rewrite the Euler equation:

$\frac{Du}{Dt}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p +g$

to the form:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+(\nabla \times u) \times u = -\nabla(\frac{p}{\rho}+\frac{1}{2}u^2+\phi)$

that basically means to prove that vector identity given there.

I'm trying to use:

- $\frac{D}{Dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+(u\nabla)$
- $\nabla (u^2) = 2(u\nabla)u-2(\nabla \times u) \times u$

I think that it's easy, but I really don't know how to solve it!

Please help me.

Comment: does "x" mean $\times$ (`\times`)?

Comment: @draks..., yes.. thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks pretty straight-forward to me. You start with

$$\frac{Du}{Dt}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p +g$$

Now use $\frac{D}{Dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+(u\nabla)$ on the left hand side to get

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+(u\nabla)u=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p +g$$

Then use $\nabla (u^2) = 2(u\nabla)u-2(\nabla \times u) \times u$ on the second term of the left hand side (first solving for $u\nabla u$, of course) to get:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac12 \nabla(u^2) + (\nabla \times u) \times u=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p +g$$

Assuming $\rho$ is constant and $g=-\nabla \phi$, you then get

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+  (\nabla \times u) \times u=-\nabla(\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p + \frac12 u^2 +\phi),$$

where $\nabla(u^2)$ has been moved to the right hand side and the $\nabla$ pulled out using the aformentioned assumptions.

Comment: thank you for your solution..

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $g =-\nabla \phi$ (conservative 'force')

And then you have what you were looking for.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u\nabla u = -\nabla (\frac{p}{\rho}+\phi) $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + (\nabla u)u +\frac{1}{2}\nabla u^2 = -\nabla (\frac{p}{\rho}+\phi)$$

and that's it.